rust clippy lint require defining magic numbres in named constant
Is there a rust clippy lint that requires defining magic numbers in named constant?
for instance:
do_something(86400);

would throw a lint error.
and
const SECONDS_IN_DAY: 86400
do_something(SECONDS_IN_DAY);

would not.

The top result here indicates not. https://www.google.com/search?q=rust%20clippy%20lint%20%22magic%20numbers%22

Maybe offtopic, but if you want protection from passing wrong number of seconds to a function, then maybe you should use a proper Duration type instead?

Looks like there isn't (yet). But I am somewhat skeptical it can be implemented in a sensible way. How would it distinguish when it is OK to use an unnamed constant and when it isn't? Because it is really not a universal truth that every constant needs to be named. And adding clippy directives everywhere is not something we might want to have.
